# How to make a Delphi installer in Inno

Tags: delphi, inno-setup

I am new to Delphi wanted to know what is the coding that you need to add in Inno Setup Compiler to make a installer for a Delphi program ??
I am using Delphi 7 and Inno Setup Compiler 5.5.3. 
Any help while be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: It depends. Start to learn from examples in the `Examples` folder of your InnoSetup installation path.

Comment: In addition to TLama's comment, Inno Setup also has a 'Script Wizard' you can use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your needs. INNOSetup uses Pascal as scripting engine, so learning curve is easy if you're coming from Delphi/Pascal world. It also has great documentation, you can get more info about almost any keyword by pressing F1 while cursor is on it, or by Googling it.

Here is the basic script that I use as a starter for creating installer for any project:

```
#define ApplicationName "FileSyncer"
#define ApplicationExe "filesyncer.exe"

[Setup]
AppName={#ApplicationName}
AppVerName={#ApplicationName}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#ApplicationName}
DefaultGroupName={#ApplicationName}
UninstallFilesDir={app}\uninstall
UninstallDisplayName={#ApplicationName}
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=.\
OutputBaseFilename=setup
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\{#ApplicationExe}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
AppMutex=FileSyncerClientInstanceMutex
WizardImageFile=setup_images\big.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=setup_images\small.bmp
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

[Files]
Source: "pfiles_x86\*.*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: not Is64BitInstallMode
Source: "pfiles_x64\*.*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: Is64BitInstallMode

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#ApplicationName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#ApplicationExe}"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{group}\Uninstall"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#ApplicationExe}"; Description: "Launch FileSyncer"; Flags: postinstall nowait skipifsilent runascurrentuser
```

For more samples, I suggest you look into *Inno Setup 5\Inno Setup Example Scripts* directory, there are alot of samples there. Also, googling something like "*innosetup sample script*" will return useful results.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I will have a look into your programming and see if I get it right .

Comment: As Inno Setup is really popular I would like to mention that it exists Embarcadero RAD Studio expert which integrates Inno Setup directly in this IDE called RAD & Installer: http://rad-installer.com/